# How to Determine Exactly What Characters are in an NSString

Tags: objective-c, parsing, nsstring, escaping, nslog

I run an XML parser that will come across something like `<tag></tag>` or `<tag>content</tag>`. Either way it stores the node content for later use.

Somewhere else down the line I want to check if the content was empty. I thought an empty node would be `@""` or even `(null)`, however neither of those are correct.

I would like to be able to determine what NSString represents the empty nodes. NSLogging the NSString results in some kind of newline, however checking it against `@"\n"` and `@"\r"` reveals it isn't either of those.

So is there some way to log the *actual* characters, escape sequences included, of an NSString? As in something like `NSLog(@"\n");` would output `"\n"` instead of a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (dirty?) trick that comes into my mind is to use the fact that `NSJSONSerialization`
escapes all control and other non-ASCII characters:

```
NSString *foo = @"a\nb\rc d\t e\001\002";

NSData *json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@[foo] options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *escaped = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:json encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", escaped);
```

Output:

```
["a\nb\rc d\t e\u0001\u0002"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Martin gave you an example of what you could do to log the characters. Or you could store it in a `NSData` and see it in hex:

```
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", data);
```

Or, if you just want to see the control characters in XML hex, but leave printable characters unchanged, you can use `CFStringTransform`:

```
NSMutableString *mutableString = [string mutableCopy];
CFStringTransform((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)mutableString, NULL, kCFStringTransformToXMLHex, NO);
```

But in answer to the question about what the parser stores when it encounters `<tag></tag>`, it all depends upon how you implemented it (and show us what you did if you have questions). But most of us would `alloc` and `init` the `NSMutableString` in `didStartElement`, we'd append string in `foundCharacters`, and then store it in our model in `didEndElement`. In that scenario, that empty tag would yield a zero length mutable string (e.g. `@""`, except a mutable string). How did you conclude it was not `@""`? If you checked for `[string isEqualToString:@""]`, that should have worked fine.

By the way, if you want to trim extra whitespace from your result, you could, in `didEndElement`, do something like:

```
self.modelObject.someStringProperty = [self.parsedString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

That way, if there were any extra spaces or newline characters, they'd get stripped out.